# how to use proxy in mac gui app

Tags: macos, proxy, fluid-mac-app-engine

I am using macOS. And I want to make my mac UI app like iTunes and other apps to use proxy network that like Shadowsocks server.

I know the proxychains using in the command line.
But how to use it by mac GUI app?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is set [shadowsocks](https://github.com/shadowsocks/ShadowsocksX-NG/releases) proxy mode as Global Mode

[image: shadowsocks]

Manual proxy configuration by listening shadowsocks port

- server address is `localhost`
- port is `1086`(mac), `1080`(linux & windows)